# Script de leilão em sql

Tags: php, mysql, query, app

estou precisando fazer um aplicativo para uma empresa de leilão de coisas usadas, daí vou precisar criar uma interface onde n clientes possam dar um lance mínimo e um lance máximo para um produto **X** e o sistema retorne o ganhador, mas fazendo uma regra para o cliente pagar o máximo possível. A regra de negócio é um pouco diferente, pois, neste projeto, ganha quem der o menor valor, mas, não o seu mínimo (não entendi o porque, mas vai ser assim rs). Por exemplo, se o valor mínimo de um cliente **C** for **R$50,00** e o máximo for de **R$ 300,00** mas na rodada de cálculo ele conseguir ganhar com **R$120,00** como o preço mais barato, ele pagaria **R$120,00** e não os **R$50,00** que é o seu mínimo. Espero ter conseguido explicar à vocês. Queria saber se tem como fazer isso com apenas uma query de mysql ou com php junto. E se der, como fazer? Alguém pode me dar uma luz? (Há também a possibilidade do empate)

---

A tabela principal de consulta teria:

- ID (pk)
- PRODUCT_ID (fk)
- CUSTOMER_ID (fk)
- MIN_PRICE (float)
- MAX_PRICE (float)
- WINNER (true or false)

Comment: Bem vindo, sua pergunta esta ampla e sem detalhes específicos do problema. Tente ser mais específico e detalhe o problema que está enfrentando.

Comment: Acho que existe problemas nessa regra, pois, caso ocorra empate e exista apenas um produto, qual será o critério para que haja um vencedor. Tem que existir uma regra para quando isso ocorrer, e quem deve defini-lá é o seu cliente, como sugestão, quando houver empates, ficará com produto quem tiver feito o lance primeiro ou quem tiver feito mais compras no site. Caso escolham a opção que quem tiver feito mais compra no site e se estiverem com empate qual próxima regra? Converse com seu cliente para que possa levantar de forma mais claras as regras antes de implementa-las.

Answer (score 1):

pelo o que entendi é igual aqueles programas de tv, do menor valor único ganha? Desta foram consegue fazer com simples sql! Analisando os valores cujo há valores duplicados, eliminando eles e posteriormente analisando os valores restantes para chegar o valor minimo.

Ex para identificar valores duplicados:

> SELECT DCB, Count(*) FROM nome_tabela
>   GROUP BY DCB
>   HAVING Count(*) > 1

com esse codigo ira retornar os valores duplicados, desta forma basta fazer uma rotina para deletar eles ou alterar um valor escondido na tabela como "valores_ilimitados".

Posteriormente de um novo SELECT retornando apenas o valor mais baixo acima dos R$50,00, e assim tera seu vencedor.

Acredito que seja desta forma que seu cliente deseja, pelo menos ofi assim que eu entendi.

Comment: Otavio, sua solução atende outra dúvida que estava tendo. Muito obrigado! :D

Answer (score 1):

Em uma única query vc não resolve isso. Trabalhar com lances de leilão são mais complexos do que aparentam ser - eu trabalho em uma [casa de leilão](http://auctionata.com). ;)

Vc terá que executar uma série de regras e filtros para chegar no cara certo. Não se apegue em ter uma unica query, isso vai mais te atrapalhar do que ajudar.

Recomendo que, ao final do leilão, que faça uma query simples, retornando uma lista - nunca uma tabela - com todos os lances, e a partir dai vc inicia os cálculos para encontrar o vencedor.

Vou enumerar aqui uma lista de atividades que vc deve executar na sua lista, vai ajudar a enxergar que uma query não é o que procura:

1. Excluir da lista todos os lances onde o lance máximo seja menor que o Preço Reserva - se houver;
2. Excluir da lista todos os lances onde o lance máximo seja menor que o lance mínimo de outro comprador;
3. Excluir da lista todos os lances onde o lance mínimo seja maior que o lance máximo de outro comprador;
4. Selecionar o comprador do PRIMEIRO lance que tiver o maior lance máximo - é importante ser o primeiro, caso mais de um comprador de o mesmo lance máximo, porém quem vence é quem deu o primeiro lance;
5. Selecionar o SEGUNDO maior lance máximo e adicionar o **Valor de Incremento**;
6. Definir que o comprador do item 4 irá pagar o valor do item 5;

**Valor de Incremento**: Valor que deverá ser adicionar ao valor do próximo lance. Por exemplo: Entre R$0-R$100 o incremento será de R$20. Entre R$100-R$500 será de R$100. Entre R$500-R$1000 será de R$250. E assim por diante.

Comment: Thiago, realmente o modelo que você explicou faz todo sentido. Vou desenvolver algo neste sentido que você disse e, dando certo, notifico aqui. Muito Obrigado pela luz.